# How to address to values of the two INPUTs of one position, if there are many positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I'm beginner in JQuery, so please help with simplifying the following function in Java Script (by converting it to JQuery).
I need to write price calculator of goods.

**a piece from HTML code**

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="5000" id="price-cb-1" onChange="calculate_price();">
    <input id="price-uts-1" class="price-count" type="number" min="1" onchange="calculate_price();" value="1">
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="9000" id="price-cb-1" onChange="calculate_price();">
    <input id="price-uts-1" class="price-count" type="number" min="1" onchange="calculate_price();" value="1">
</li>
```

.....there are 30 elements of

```
 <li>..</li>
```

with different values(prices). I need to add all prices, which are multiplied by quantity, then add all of it, and get total amount.
So how to address to values at the same time of TWO inputs by using JQuery?

**Java Script**

```
var sum = 0;    
var prefixCheckbox = "price-cb-";
  for (var i = 1, ids = ($('.price')).length; i<=ids; i++) {
     if (document.getElementById(prefixCheckbox+i).checked === true){
       sum+=(document.getElementById(prefixUnits+i).value)* 
       (document.getElementById(prefixCheckbox+i).value)
      }
$('#total').html(sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `change` event of both types of your input you can loop over each checked element, multiplying its value with the quantity. Try this:

```
$('.option, .price-count').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;          
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
        sum += $(this).val() * $(this).next('.price-count').val();
    });

    $('#total').html(sum);
}).change();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozq7rbn9/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Please help to solve another issue with printing out name, quantity and unit of measure of every checked items.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.calculator input').on('change', function() {
    var lis = $(this).closest('li:has(:checked)');
    var total = 0
    lis.each(function() {
        total += +$(this).find(':checkbox').val() * +$(this).find('[type=number]').val();
    });
    $('#total').text( total );
})
.trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="calculator">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="5000" id="price-cb-1">
    <input id="price-uts-1" class="price-count" type="number" min="1" value="1">
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option" value="9000" id="price-cb-1">
    <input id="price-uts-1" class="price-count" type="number" min="1" value="1">
</li>
</ul>
TOTAL: 
<div id="total"></div>
```